# Firestore batch set is only inserting the last item

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4

I'm trying to batch create a bunch of documents from the array items, where each item is a map of key-value pairs. I've got multiple values in my array, but for some reason the only item that ever gets inserted into the db is the last item in the array.

What am I doing wrong here? Or can I only use setData once in the history of the commit?

```
let wordsRef = db.collection("items").document()

for item in items {
    batch.setData(item, forDocument: wordsRef)
}

batch.commit() { err in
    // error reporting
}
```

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. Just simply move the wordsRef inside the for loop, like I have done below. Hopefully this helps...

**Code:**

```
for item in items {
    let wordsRef = db.collection("items").document()
    batch.setData(item, forDocument: wordsRef)
}

batch.commit() { err in
    // error reporting
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way each document will have different IDs! Thanks for that.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! 